# Iterate over array of items in Jekyll Frontmatter

Tags: jekyll

My front matter:

```
menu_links:
- donate: "/donate"
- shop: "/shop"
```

My loop:

```
{% for menu_link in page.menu_links %}
  <div><a class="menu-item" href="{{ menu_link[1] }}">{{ menu_link[0] }}</a></div>
{% endfor %}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

The way it is defined is parsed as: `[{"donate"=>"/donate"}, {"shop"=>"/shop"}]`

so you would be able to access them with:

```
{{page.menu_links[0]['donate']}}
{{page.menu_links[1]['shop']}}
```

A better one would be:

```
menu_links:
 donate: "/donate"
 shop: "/shop"
```

so you can access directly:

```
{{page.menu_links['donate']}}
{{page.menu_links['shop']}}
```

then your original code would work.

Comment: Thanks but I needed a programmatic solution since I was using Jekyll Admin and users may need to change keys and/or values in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
{% for menu_link in page.menu_links %}
  {% for item in menu_link %}
    <div><a class="menu-item" href="{{ item[1] }}">{{ item[0] }}</a></div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Each item needs to be looped through a second time in order to get the key/value pair of each menu_link.

Comment: `item` is not undocumented; just declared in for loop. it could be anything i.e. `foo` in `{% for foo in menu_link %}` & `i` in `{% for i in menu_link %}`

Comment: updated the solution: I needed to loop within the loop to get the key/val pair. your comment clarified nothing for me btw